# Chrome wants to save pdf as system.byte[]

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, pdf

When saving a viewed pdf document with IE11 it displays the correct file name and extension, but Chrome shows it as System.Byte[]. Changing the file name to MyFileName.pdf and saving it works, but is not the ideal solution.

Here is the code returning the document from the database and displaying it in a vb.net webforms popup page.

```
  strSQL = "SELECT PDF_Document FROM A_Documents WHERE Document_ID = " & vID
        Dim vDocument As Byte() = vService.ReturnScalarByte(strSQL, Session("HOAID"))
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", vDocument.Length.ToString())
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & vDocument.ToString())
        Response.ContentType = ("application/pdf")
        Response.BinaryWrite(vDocument)
```

Comment: `vDocument.ToString()` is going to give you `System.Byte[]` so you're actually telling the browser the file name is `System.Byte[]` so chrome is actually doing the correct thing.

Comment: Why does it work perfectly with IE and FF?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Chrome uses it's own pdf viewer that doesn't work very well (especially in a iFRAME popup).

Until they fix this the customer needs to enter chrome://plugins in the address bar, disable Chrome PDF Viewer and enable Adobe Reader.

Unless there is a better answer out there I will just put this down to an unfixed bug in Chrome

Comment: While Chrome's PDF Viewer often is to blame, in your case out isn't, cf. Musa's comment.